# Why does this Update query add records?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two databases, n and p. Below is the Update query I'm trying to use. I would like it to add dates and project numbers from n to p. For some reason after I run the query I end up with more records in p then I began with. What is going on here?

```
UPDATE DatesAndProjectNumbers

AS n 

LEFT JOIN Projects 

AS p 

ON (n.[Customer Number] = p.[Customer Number]) 

AND (n.[Measure Received] = p.[Measure Received]) 

SET p.PO = [n].[PO], p.[PGI/Invoice] = [n].[PGI/Invoice], p.Cancelled = [n].[Cancelled];
```

Comment: why did you left join to projects when that is the table you are updating?

Comment: Use INNER join rather than LEFT. You might take a look at this: https://blog.udemy.com/sql-update-join/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/

```
UPDATE DatesAndProjectNumbers

AS n 

INNER JOIN Projects 

AS p 

ON (n.[Customer Number] = p.[Customer Number]) 

AND (n.[Measure Received] = p.[Measure Received]) 

SET p.PO = [n].[PO], p.[PGI/Invoice] = [n].[PGI/Invoice], p.Cancelled = [n].[Cancelled];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works great. Are you able to elaborate why the original creates records? I thought update queries cannot do that? -Thanks again-

Comment: Go through this link http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/